# "admin" Subdirectory Triggering (unintentially) Django Admin Pages

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am having trouble with some custom admin pages triggering the Django admin site instead of displaying my custom pages.

My **urls.py** follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... trimmed ...

    # Admin pages
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),                       
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Lobby Visitor Log
    url(r'^visitorLog', include('lobbyVisitorLog.urls')),
)
```

In my `lobbyVisitorLog` app I have the following directory structure, leading to "admin" pages

```
lobbyVisitorLog
  - templates
      - admin
```

And my **lobbyVisitorLog/urls.py** follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('visitorLog.views',
    url(r'^/$', views.home, name='homeView'),
    url(r'^/search', views.search, name='searchView'),
    url(r'^/submit', views.submit, name='submitView'),

    url(r'^/admin/$', views.adminView, name='adminView'),
    url(r'^/admin/import/$', views.adminImportView, name='adminImportView'),

    url(r'^/(?P<guest_type>\w+)$', views.logEntry, name='logEntryView'),
)
```

The **views.py** for the admin index page looks like this:

```
def adminView(request):
    return render(request, 'admin/index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I go to "mysite/visitorLog/admin/" I get the Django admin site with the following message: “You don't have permission to edit anything.”

However, if I change my "admin" directory to "utils" (or whatever else, other then "admin") and update my `views.py` accordingly, everything appears as expected!  This is okay, I can deal with my directory being called "utils" but it will annoy me... just enough.

What is happening that is causing the Django admin page to load instead of my custom pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default django first checks each of the paths you have in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` for 'admin/index.html'. If it doesn't find it there, it starts searching in the templates directory for each app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

If `'django.contrib.admin'` is listed first in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it will use the identically named 'admin/index.html' template from the django.contrib.admin app.

Moving `'django.contrib.admin'` to the last position in `INSTALLED_APPS` should allow it to find 'admin/index.html' in your lobbyVisitorLog app first, but this will break the admin site by cause it to use 'admin/index.html' from your app, lobbyVisitorLog.

A good way to solve this is to always have a sub-directory named after your app within your app's templates directory. For example:

```
lobbyVisitorLog
  - templates
    - lobbyVisitorLog
      - admin
        - index.html
```

and then update your view's template path:

```
def adminView(request):
    return render(request, 'lobbyVisitorLog/admin/index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can find more on how Django loads templates [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)

Comment: I added a section regarding the URLs (they were incorrect too). Feel free to edit it or remove it as you will. Figured putting the extra in this answer was better than creating a new one. You may disagree.

Comment: I believe his URLs are correct.  The urls in lobbyVisitorLog/urls.py are included in the main urls.py on a ^visitorLog pattern (which matches and removes the /visitorLog piece before passing it to lobbyVisitorLog/urls.py), so it will only match domain.com/visitorLog/admin/

Comment: You're right - teach me for not verifying when contributing to another persons' answer. Sorry, I blame Sunday!